# Clearing the canvas from any drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This JS code when executed in the console works fine but the public method `clean()` does not wipe out every thing on the canvas.
The code has other methods but the one which is failing is the cleaning.
`ctx` has a value so it is not null.
How can it be fixed so that it cleans the canvas? Thanks

```
signRect = function() {
  let tr_sign = null;
  let ctx = null;
  let canvas_sign = null;
  const makeCanvas = () => {
    if (canvas_sign) return canvas_sign;
    canvas_sign = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas_sign.position = 'absolute';
    canvas_sign.width = 300;
    canvas_sign.height = 170;
    canvas_sign.id = 'signature';
    canvas_sign.style.border = '1px solid black';
    canvas_sign.style.top = '-75px';
    canvas_sign.style.left = '-50px';
    canvas_sign.style.opacity = '0.5';
    canvas_sign.style.position = 'absolute';
    ctx = canvas_sign.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    return canvas_sign;
  };

  return {
    clean: () => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_sign.width, canvas_sign.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: if you first `makeCanvas()` and than `someNewSignRect.clean()` it should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to explicitly close the path see [this](http://codetheory.in/why-clearrect-might-not-be-clearing-canvas-pixels/) for more information.

Beyond that you can use the `canvas.width = canvas.width;` "hack".